# Why having minHeight in TextView will add extra spacing on its neighbourhood component

Tags: android

Currently, I have a layout as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:text="BAC"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/code_text_view"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bye"
        android:id="@+id/symbol_text_view"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the outcome

[image]

Note, **there's spacing around top & bottom of `symbol_text_view`** (The long text which shows Bank of America, Bank...)

I don't expect such to happen. Although there's `minHeight=48dp` on `code_text_view` (The text view with red background), but I'm sure `symbol_text_view`'s height is already more than 48dp. I don't expect `code_text_view` cause any extra top and bottom spacing.

---

I replace `code_text_view` with a `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/code_exchange_linear_layout"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="BAC"
            android:id="@+id/code_text_view"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exchange_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="NYSE"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
   </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bank of America Bye"
        android:id="@+id/symbol_text_view"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get the following outcome, **without extra top and bottom spacing**

[image]

May I know, why there's an extra top and bottom spacing, for the 1st case?

### Update:

Some interesting observation by stackoverflower.

> I am checking your code and interesting thing I found is that, when I
>   am removing center_vertical attribute from code_text_view in your
>   above xml. It also cause removing of top and bottom padding.

Comment: I am checking your code and interesting thing I found is that, when I am removing `center_vertical` attribute from `code_text_view` in your above xml. It also cause removing of top and bottom padding.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why?